# Snow Leopard + Grails 1.1.1 + Groovy 1.6.5

Tags: grails, groovy, osx-snow-leopard

I have Grails 1.1.1 and Groovy 1.6.3 on Leopard.  Will I have any issues with this combo: Snow Leopard + Grails 1.1.1 + Groovy 1.6.5?

Answer (score 0):

Not at all, I've been running Grails 1.1.1 as well as the recent milestone builds under Snow Leopard for the past couple of months. We have been using Netbeans for development and I have started toying with the new Eclipse (SpringSource) integration without any problems. Grails commands also run just fine from the command line.

Comment: Great.  Thank you.  Now I can use Snow Leopard!

Answer (score 0):

Snow Leopard marks the first 64-bit Mac OS X, however, the Java Virtual Machine handles all of the stuff you need for 64-bit compatibility.

Have a lot of fun on Snow Leopard!

Comment: What exactly do you mean?  I'm running 64-bit Leopard (OS X 10.5) on my MacBook.  Flipping it around, Snow Leopard is the first Mac OS to come with a 32-bit Java 6 JVM (necessary for Google Web Toolkit hosted mode using the Google Eclipse plug-in).

Comment: According to http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/eclipse-java-and-snow-leopard it comes with both 32 and 64-bit JVM, with the 64-bit JVM being the default. However, you can change your default to be 32-bit on the Java Preferences application.